# Collect warnings and let Sphinx raise them

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am using [autodoc-process-docstring](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html?highlight=autodoc-process-docstring#event-autodoc-process-docstring) to check for undocumented members

```
def warn_undocumented_members(app, what, name, obj, options, lines):
    if what in MEMBERS_TO_WARN and not lines:
        sys.stderr.write("<autodoc> WARNING: {} is undocumented: {}\n".format(what, name))

app.connect('autodoc-process-docstring', warn_undocumented_members)
```

Is there any possibility to bubble up the warnings in Sphinx?

I looked into [the app object](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html?highlight=app.connect#sphinx.application.Sphinx.connect) but could not find anything satisfying. The only thing I found is raising a [SphinxError](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html?highlight=app.connect#sphinx.errors.SphinxError) in the if clause, but this is stopping the build instead of collecting all warnings. Also this is not respecting the `-W` flag of `sphinx-build` (I always have a hard error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sphinx components pass warnings through the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) facility, for which Sphinx defines custom adapters in [`sphinx.util.logging`](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/4.x/sphinx/util/logging.py). If you use the loggers provided there, Sphinx will treat your warnings the same as its own and respect the `-W` flag that turns them into errors.

```py
import sphinx
logger = sphinx.util.logging.getLogger('sphinx.ext.autodoc')

def warn_undocumented_members(app, what, name, obj, options, lines):
    if what in MEMBERS_TO_WARN and not lines:
        logger.warning(f'{what} is undocumented: {name}', type='autodoc')

def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-process-docstring', warn_undocumented_members)
```